# Web servers Error : Message: Missing message for key "" in WAS 7

Tags: webserver, websphere, websphere-7

I am trying to create webservers under `Servers ---> Server Types ----> Web Servers` ----> New

[image]

**Error :**

An error occurred while processing request: 
Message: Missing message for key ""

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Missing message for key ""
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.bean.MessageTag.doStartTag(Unknown Source)
    at _ibmjsp.secure.layouts._stepsLayout._jspService(_stepsLayout.java:1040)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1655)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1595)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:104)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:932)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:239)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:341)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.isclite.container.controller.InformationController.processForwardConfig(InformationController.java:217)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1655)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1595)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:104)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:932)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:341)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.isclite.container.controller.InformationController.processForwardConfig(InformationController.java:217)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1655)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1595)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistence(WSCUrlFilter.java:927)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:494)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:315)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:932)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3826)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:288)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1016)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1772)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)
```

AS shown below,

[image]

Don't have logging service up and running. I faced this issue when i tried to create a new server after deleting the old one ( incorrect one ).

Interestingly when i try to logout it will show deleted server details as shown below

[image]

***In Precise WAS is looking for file which doesn't exists after DELETE ( browsing through directories )***

```
:/u01/profiles.7.0.0.11/appsrv01/config/cells / taspmociias304Cell01 / nodes / webserver1-node / node.xml
```

Why did i delete ?

```
Named wrong host-name, i.e instead of appsrv01 i named webserver1-node
```

Valid path does exists in this path

```
:/u01/profiles.7.0.0.11/appsrv01/config/cells/taspmociias304Cell01/nodes/appsrv01
```

Comment: This looks like a product issue.  I would recommend opening a PMR with IBM.

Comment: After you deleted the 'incorrect' Webserver, did you `save` before you clicked on `new`? Can you still see the incorrect webserver in your console (since you can on the file system)? I've had some luck in the past manually cleaning up things on the filesystem after a near-fatal `delete/save` experience. You may need to check your config xml files (`resources.xml` and `serverindex.xml`) and try to clean it up manually and then try to click `new`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep! as you guys mentioned. it's a PRODUCT defect.